# Filter vector based on values from a column

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector

```
letters <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

I also have a table named `df` which has a column containing values such as `"a_1", "b_2", c_3"`, ...etc.

How do I filter `letters` to only keep characters that are available in the column from `df`.

For example, `letters <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")` and `df$column` values are `"a_1", "d_3", "b_7"`. `letters` should now become `c("a", "b", "d")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may remove the `_` and one or more digits (`\\d+`) from the column, use `%in%` to create a logical vector and subset the `letters` object

```
letters[letters %in% sub("_\\d+", "", df$column)]
[1] "a" "b" "d"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(column = c("a_1", "d_3", "b_7"))
```